# React three fiber passing function arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I made a function to return a material based on a value

```
function MyMat(height){

  if(height > 2) {
    return (<meshStandardMaterial color="#878787" flatShading={true} />)
  } 
  else if(height > 1) {
    return (<meshStandardMaterial color="#674942" flatShading={true} />)
  }

  return (
    <meshStandardMaterial color="black" flatShading={true} />
  )
}
```

and when I call it in my canvas likes this

```
<MyMat height = {4} />
```

it works but the the value 4 (height) isn't passed, how can I pass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write height as object props, not as a value.
Replace `MyMat(height)` with `MyMat({height})`